# How can I rerun an Autosys box job one time if its last job fails?

Tags: shell, autosys

What is the best way to rerun automatically a failed box imidieltly when its last job fails?
The box has 3 jobs, if last job fails i want to rerun the whole box only once.
I thought maybe to create another job to run upon failure of the last one that will be out of the box and will execute a shell script with fs/sendevent command to force start the box ...
Is there any other way to do it?

Thank you